# Heroku ACN (for SSL) failled - my DNS are correct. What to do?

Tags: ssl, heroku

I'm facing a problem trying to deploy ACN on my Heroku domain.

I think that my DNS records are correct:

```
Domain Name                -----  DNS Record Type  ----- DNS Target
membre.smaltonline.com     ----- CNAME -----             membre.smaltonline.com.herokudns.com
www.membre.smaltonline.com ----- CNAME -----             www.membre.smaltonline.com.herokudns.com
```

But when I use the `heroku certs:auto` command to enable the ACN, it fails.

I've read the reason why it could fail on https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management#troubleshooting, but I think I'm not in any of those situations.

Do you guys have an idea of where to look at? How to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see this in the DNS lookup response:

1) `www.membre.smaltonline.com`

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.membre.smaltonline.com.    IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.membre.smaltonline.com. 3600 IN CNAME   www.membre.smaltonline.com.herokudns.com.
```

2) `membre.smaltonline.com`

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;membre.smaltonline.com.        IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
membre.smaltonline.com. 3576    IN  CNAME   smalt-membership.herokuapp.com.
```

So it seems your `membre.smaltonline.com` name is still a `CNAME` to `.herokuapp.com`, not `.herokudns.com`.

Comment: Thank you Jens, I changed it. I didn't understand something : that .herokudns.com address are not browsable. So I changed my DNS and it works fine :)